# Shell script problems

Tags: linux

So I'm doing some work on shell script. I have this code:

```
Echo "5  Matt  male"
Echo "8  Sarah  female"
Echo "9  Paul  male"
```

I am meant to set a threshold number of 6 which will only output the lines whose numbers are above 6. Hence the lines containing sarah and Paul. But I have no idea on how to do this. Im so sorry but it is also meant to print only the ones that also contain "female"

Comment: Start by showing what you tried first.

Comment: I'm sorry. But I'm unbelievably bad at Unix so I dont know what to try. I hope you can still answer the question

Comment: `Echo` should be spelled `echo`. Linux shells are case sensitive.

Comment: I knew that, was just in a rush typing the question. So any answers yet

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28849786/770830).

Comment: Lol. Was getting no response so decided to post it again.

Answer (score 0):

your date need to be stored in file.txt.

file.txt:

```
5  Matt  male
8  Sarah  female
9  Paul  male
```

`cat file.txt | awk '{ if( $1 > 5 && $3=="female") print $0}'`

If you don't know the usage of awk, take a look this http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/awkbook/

Comment: `print $0` would be enough.

Comment: Yeah, it is. I will modify it.

Comment: Sorry but it's also meant to print only the ones >5 and contain female in it

Comment: I think you can modify my answer to achieve your female containing.

Comment: So I just add pattern/ female/ to it and that's all?

Comment: rechk my answer, i added it.